# Rephrasing the "if" part of the statement of the Principle of Uniform Boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

I am trying to better and more rigorously understand the Principle of Uniform Boundedness (PUB). Recall that the statement of PUB reads:

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach Spaces and suppose that $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathcal B(X,Y)$. If for every $x\in X$ it follows that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|T_nx\|<\infty$, then $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|T_n\|<\infty$.

Consider, in particular, the part which reads *"... for every $x\in X$ it follows that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|T_nx\|<\infty$ ..."*. Now this precisely means that,
$$\forall x\in X,\,\sup\{\|T_nx\|:n\in\mathbb N\}<\infty,$$
which is equivalent to the statement that,
$$\forall x\in X,\,\exists M\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}\,\forall\, n\in\mathbb N:\|T_nx\|\le M.$$
**My question:** how, exactly, is this equivalent to the statement that,
$$\forall x\in X:\|x\|\le1,\,\exists M\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}\,\forall\, n\in\mathbb N:\|T_nx\|\le M?$$
Note that the set of those $x\in X:\|x\|\le1$ is precisely the ball in $X$ centered at $0_X$ of radius $1$. I think I am close in making the connection, and I am convinced that it is to do with the fact that the operator norm can be defined as,
$$\|T\|=\sup\{\|Tx\|:\|x\|\le1\},$$
but I am not sure how I should deal with the quantifiers that slipping this definition into the above brings with it. Can anybody indicate or highlight how the equivalence should be drawn out?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the proof of this theorem is a few pages long.  You ask, "how, exactly, is this equivalent to ...?"   The only answer I have is to read the proof.  It is not at all obvious to me that the first statement implies the second.  It took me a long time to come up with a proof many years ago when I was thinking about it.

Comment: Is it obvious to you when $X$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: @lightxbulb     He is trying to prove that $\sup_n||T_n||<\infty$.  How does the fact that $ ||T_n x||\leq||T_n||\cdot ||x||$ help?

Comment: As written, in your final statement $M$ is allowed to depend on $x$. Is this what you intended? If so, this is straightforward. One implication is trivial since if you have such an $M$ for every $x$, you certainly have it for all $x$ with $\|x\| \leq 1$. For the other direction, note that $\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\| = 1$ and $\|T_n(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) \| \leq M \implies \|T_n x\| \leq M \|x\| = M'$. If this is not what you intended then this is the content of the PUB and you should read the proof.

Comment: @Rhys Steele, I played about with it a little more and yes, what you indicated was what I was thinking to try ... really nothing more than that. As I said, more to do with the statement and not the content of PUB itself.

Comment: @RhysSteele, if you post that as an answer I will be happy to accept.

Comment: The implication that is stated as being trivial is not in fact trivial. It is only trivial in the way you have phrased the problem because you have ordered the statements in the proposition incorrectly. The $\forall n$ in the line under “My Question” should come before all the other statements in that line..in particular it comes before the $\forall x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One implication is trivial since if we can find an $M$ for every $x$ then we can certainly find an $M$ for every $x$ satisfying $\|x\| \leq 1$.

For the non-trivial implication, pick an arbitrary $x \in X$. Then $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ satisfies $\|y\| = 1$ and so there is an $N$ such that 
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|T_n y \| \leq N.$$
However, $\|T_ny\| = \frac{1}{\|x\|} \|T_nx\|$ and so, setting $M = N \|x\|$, we get
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|T_n x \| \leq M$$
as desired.

Comment: I'm afraid that I might be reading too much into it, but if the statement we are taking as our assumption in the non-trivial direction is *"**for all** $x\in\mathcal B_X(0,1)$ ..."*, why is it sufficient to consider only $y:=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ for any choice of $x\in X$? How does this cover those $y\in\mathcal B_X(0,1)$ for which $\|y\|<1$?

Comment: Why wouldn't this cover $x$ with $\|x\| < 1$? (other than $x=0$ as a trivial special case I didn't bother mentioning) For such an $x$, $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ has norm $1$ and hence we can still find an $N$ for $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and proceed as in the answer.

Comment: I see that such $x$ can still be normalised and we can proceed as above, I think I'm just turning it over in my head too much. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: It might help to notice that what this really shows is an extra equivalence. It shows that $[\forall x, \, \exists M \dots] \implies [\forall x: \|x\| \leq 1, \, \exists M \dots] \implies [\forall x: \|x\| = 1, \, \exists M \dots] \implies [\forall x, \, \exists M \dots]$ where the first two implications are trivial.

Comment: This is in a similar manner to showing that the different forms of the operator norm are equivalent?

Comment: The sets over which you quantify $x$ are in the same order, yes. This isn't very uncommon (or surprising) since often you can use rescaling arguments like the one I did here.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insights here, Rhys; these have given me a lot to think over.